# Why does conventional electricity flow out of + in a battery, but out of - in components?

Tags: components, charge

It seems like when electricity flows out of + in a battery it should be attracted by a - end of a component, but it's not like that. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It is like that.

Current is "attracted" to the negative end of the component.

That is why you have to attach it to the *positive* end of the component... so that it will *have to flow through* the component to reach the negative end.

If you connected directly, it would not flow "uphill" to reach the positive end, thus doing no work (bypassing the component).

### Consider this circuit:

[image]

I've created a contrived circuit and indicated the polarity of the *component's* terminal closest to the top of the figure. We can draw some conclusions:

R1 and R2 are resistors, a component through which current may pass equally well in both directions (polarities). Consequently, the polarity of the component is determined by how it is connected in the circuit. In the case of R1, the top most terminal is connected to the battery negative and current moves through the component upwards. The situation is reversed for R2, current moving downwards.

D1 and D2 are diodes. Diodes are polar. They conduct preferentially well in one direction. For this reason, we say, practically, that it has a "positive" and "negative" end. This isn't strictly true since the voltage of the "negative" end could easily exceed the "positive" end  as is the case for D2 (better terms are "anode" and "cathode").

The "positive" end of the light emitting diode is the base of the triangle (for D1, the edge top-most in the figure), the cathode (the horizontal line) is the "negative" end. So for D1, the current proceeds downwards. However, for D2, you would expect the current to proceed upwards, but this isn't possible due to the battery's orientation (current won't flow backwards into the battery when it's the only source in a static circuit).

Further, current won't flow downwards through the diode (that's backwards through the diode) as the diode's behavior prevents it (diode's only allow anode -> cathode flow). As a result, no current flows through D2 and it will not emit light as a result.

### A note about polarity

It has become convention in electrical engineering to define current flow as positive to negative. EE is an applied field and progressed faster than the physics it relies on (who cares if the models are correct so long as they work, right?!). We now know that electronic currents are composed of moving electrons (negative charges) and the gaps they leave behind (positive "holes").

In actuality, currents consisting of negative charges are moving in the direction opposite to the way we conceptualize them... but opposite charges moving in the opposite direction has the same effect, so our previous model works just fine, which is why it has remained in use.

Comment: "The 'positive' end of the light emitting diode is the top of the triangle" This makes it sound like the tip of the triangle (at least to me, the top of a triangle is the tip,) I think it should be reworded to the base of the triangle or the cathode is shown as a bar and the anode as a triangle.

Comment: @Garrett -- good pick up. I've edited as requested to improve. Cheers.

Comment: Current is not just the flow of electrons, any charged particle will do: ions in solutions, protons in plasma.....
There is even displacement current with no charge, this flows thru the space between the plates in caps.
There are also holes ( but you can argue this is still electron flow )
In EE most current is electron flow, but the deeper understanding is why Physics is so far ahead of EE :).

Comment: @Russ -- Yup. +1 Physics! :)

Comment: the LED connected directly to the battery is painful to look at

Answer (score 3):

A key point is that we name the "+" terminal of a two-terminal component that way because it's the one that's (normally) at a more positive potential. If current flows *in* to that terminal, it means that energy is being delivered *to the component*. If current flows *out* of the more-positive terminal, it means the component is delivering energy *to the rest of the circuit*.

In a resistor, the delivered energy is dissipated as heat; In a capacitor, it's stored in an electrical field between the plates; etc.

A battery is different because it contains a reservoir of energy stored in chemical bonds, and it converts that to electrical energy which it delivers to the rest of the circuit. And to do that, its current must flow out of its more-positive terminal.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing out on is the concept of sources and sinks and the whether or not a component is a supplier of energy or a consumer of energy.

1) A +'ve voltage supply that sources current (+'ve) => +'ve X +'ve = +'ve
- it is a source of power.

2)  A +'ve terminal on a component which sinks current (-'ve) => +'ve X -'ve = -'ve
- it is a consumer of power.

3) A -'ve terminal of a component which sources current (+'ve) => -'ve X +'ve = -'ve
- it is a consumer of power

4) a -'ve terminal of a Supply that sinks current (-'ve) => -'ve X -'ve = +'ve
- it is a source of power

Another way of looking at it is that the current does see the other terminal of the supply THROUGH the component and the +'ve and -'ve markings are simply a way of ensuring that you connect the device in the orientation that corresponds to the operation you want.

YOu might find #3 above confusing, but it explains what happens when - say you place a resistor in series on a component's -'ve or "gnd" terminal.

It's a convention in *ALL* of sciences which works perfectly fine.  There are systems that have both +'ve and -'ve carriers of charge - Anion and Cations in electrochemical systems as an example.

Another thing that confuses people is the special case of ground.  It can both sink and source current.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is labeled with Voltage (potential) labels, not Current (flow) labels.

Sometimes it is useful or helpful to put little labels on your diagrams, power supplies, or components, to show which way the current flows. When you do that, it is more common to use little arrows, because, as you have observed, +/- signs already have a different meaning.

When you use current flow labels, things have  IN and OUT, and you connect an IN to an OUT.
When you use potential labels, things have + and -, and you connect all the + together and all the - together.